# tkinter instances not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make GUI and I thought to separate GUI into several classes. (Note: I'm very new to programming in general). In main class I would call instances (parts of GUI) and use grid to create complete GUI. Problem is as I see it that in my main class should decide where to put instances but only last instance is shown.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Code(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.frm = ttk.LabelFrame(parent, text="frm_code", height=130, width=500)
        # make grid with just one cell - I thought this is local grid placement
        self.frm.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E))
        self.frm.grid_propagate(False)

        self.mess_sql = tk.Message(
            self.frm,
            text="""Veeeery long text""",
            width = 470
        )
        self.mess_sql.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E))

class Header(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.frm = ttk.LabelFrame(parent, text="frm_header")
        # make grid with just one cell - I thought this is local grid placement
        self.frm.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E))

        self.btn_ok = ttk.Button(self.frm, text="OK", command=self.click_ok)
        self.btn_cancel= ttk.Button(self.frm, text="Cancel", command=self.click_cancel)

        self.btn_ok.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.btn_cancel.grid(row=0, column=1)

    # just some test functions
    def click_ok(self):
        print("OK clicked")
    def click_cancel(self):
        print("Cancel clicked")

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.header = Header(parent)
        self.code = Code(parent)

        # this should place widgets, but for now does nothing
        self.header.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.header.grid(row=1, column=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You placed the header frame twice. The line should be `self.code.grid(row=1, column=0)`

Comment: Yes, this is error, but even if I comment those lines I get same behavior. What confuse me are those lines below comments `# make grid with just one cell - I thought this is local grid placement` as it seems that they determine placement and not grid in main class

Comment: I have seen this answer [link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068529/1403984 and modified my code to